# Trying to put command's help in a file on CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to get DISKPART's help in text file.

```
    help DISKPART>a.txt
```

But Diskpart opens another window and helpis there, not in my file.

And there is a second problem with help SC:

```
    help SC>b.txt
```

help SC asks me to watch help about QUERY and QUERYEX, I want to tell it YES automatically. But if I write

```
    echo Y|help SC
```

It doesn't accept my yes and asks that question from user. What is the problem with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISKPART requires elevation, so if you run it from a non-elevated batch file it will run in a separate window.  You'll need to elevate before running it.  (Forcing it to run without elevation doesn't work; you just get an access denied error.)

It looks as though SC reads directly from the console rather than from standard input.  You could try writing a program to launch sc.exe using [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the [`CREATE_NO_WINDOW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) process creation flag, so that there's no console for it to get input from.  Or you could use the [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to synthesize a keystroke.

(It would be a lot easier to do this by hand and keep a copy for future reference!)